# Nuget package references and depencies problem

Tags: c#, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore, nuget-spec

I have c# projects with packages and references in hierarchy like this

```
Project-A
  package1
  package2
  Project-B
    package3
    package4
    Project-C
      package5
      package6
```

So project A references some packages and Project B, which references another packages and Project C, which references some third packets. I need to pack the project A into a NuGet Package so that in it has dependencies to all of the packages like this :

```
Project-A-Nuget
  package1
  package2
  package3
  package4
  package5
  package6
```

I already tried to use .nuspec file to define dependencies like above but in that case i cant download my package because it tries to find and restore my referenced projects as packages.
I tried to use just dotnet pack, but in that case it is not registering packages as dependencies

My .nuspec file looks like this

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd">
    <metadata>
        <id>ProjectA.Nuget</id>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <title>ProjectA.Nuget</title>
        <authors>Me</authors>
        <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
        <description>Description.</description>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency id="package1" version="[6.0.11]" />
            <dependency id="package2" version="[6.0.11]" />
            <dependency id="package3" version="[6.0.11]" />
            <dependency id="package4" version="[6.0.11]" />
            <dependency id="package5" version="[6.0.11]" />
            <dependency id="package6" version="[6.0.11]" />
        </dependencies>
    </metadata>
</package>
```

Comment: Is Project B and Project C also nuget packages? How are you going to resolve those dependencies when running Project A?

Comment: Do you using `<IsPackable>true</IsPackable>` attribute on the A project?

Comment: If a class library produces a NuGet package, msbuild will convert `<ProjectReference>`s to `<PackageReference>`s for consuming projects

Comment: @Pieterjan that is the problem. I want my referenced projects to be included as compile time assemblies, but when I achieve that, I can't specify my package dependencies

Comment: @AleksandrTereshchenko It does not make a difference for me. I tried with and without it.

Comment: @gunr2171 No, they are not nuget packages, just referenced projects in the same solution. I need them to be included in the nuget package as compile time assemblies.

Answer (score 0):

To include dlls that used via `ProjectReference` or `Reference` in your nuget package then follow the steps:

1. Download [nuget.exe](https://www.nuget.org/downloads)
2. Add `<IsPackable>true</IsPackabe>` to `<PropertyGroup>` of your .csproj file
3. run `nuget pack -IncludeReferencedProjects` ([nuget pack command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/cli-reference/cli-ref-pack))

Comment: I tried that way, it is not working for package references. Meaning that assemblies link correctly, but my dependencies are not shown

Comment: @SourCreamKun do you have nuspec file or not? If so, then try to remove it and move all tags(Author, Version, etc.) to Directory.build.props or csproj files

Comment: Tried both ways, with and without. With .nuspec file I can see my package dependencies, but not linked assemblies and the other way around so without it I can see assemblies but not dependencies

Comment: Update your question please and add .csproj content